# MediaPlayer.Volume control

Tags: c#, xna, media-player

I have a slider where I get a value from 0 to 100 to adjust the volume. The MediaPlayer.Volume expects a value between 0.0 and 1.0 while 0=-96db and 1=-0db. Currently I use the following code to adjust the linear values from my slider:

```
 float newVolume = (float)(Math.Sqrt(sliderValue) / 10);
 newVolume = MathHelper.Clamp(newVolume, 0.0001f, 1.0f);
 MediaPlayer.Volume = newVolume;
```

This works better then directly mapping the 0 to 100 values but in the higher half the adjustment is still rather low compared to the lower half. Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Human ears are logarithmic, not quadratic.  Volume should already compensate for that if its units are decibels.  You'd use Math.Log if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, where 'value' is from 0 to 100

```
        value = MathHelper.Clamp(value, 0f, 100f);
        var logged = Math.Log(value + 1) / Math.Log(101);
        MediaPlayer.Volume = MathHelper.Clamp((float)logged, 0.001f, 1.0f);
```